# How to remove layout scroll bar in primefaces?

Tags: layout, primefaces

I am dealing with primefaces and I wanted to use p:layout instead of my own layout. But the p:layoutUnit components are scrollable by default. When I wanted to remove scroll bar I tried :

```
       <style type="text/css">
            .ui-layout-center {                    
                overflow:hidden !important;
            }

            .ui-layout-center .ui-layout-unit-content {
                overflow:hidden !important;
            }     
        </style>
```

and it removed the scrollbar, but now I cannot see the whole page (the web page became non-scrollable). How can I solve this, do I have to use my own layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using overflow use overflow-x this worked for me and the horizontal scrollbar went away keeping the vertical scroll bar

Comment: i use my own layout, your solution didn't work for me but i will accept the answer. thank you.